# How to compare two folders with their files and make sure they are the same

Tags: md5, md5sum, md5-file

I want to compare two folders(they both have the same zip files). I want to make sure they are exactly the same. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do a find on the directory, executing a checksum on each file within that directory.  I sort the output and then do a final checksum on the sorted output.  If the final checksum of each directory is the same, I think it is safe to assume they are the same.

The command I use is

```
find _dir_ -type f -exec cksum {} \; | sort | cksum
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried to compare two folders with the same files so check the file integrity. However the both folders returns different hash value.

Comment: You could skip the last checksum and just redirect the sorted output into two different files.  You can then do a diff on those files to see what individual files have different checksums.